# Error when rendering google map

Tags: android

i get the following stack trace, that never points out my code, when trying to load the mapfragment into a pager view.

i am not even sure where to begin addressing this, thoughts?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app, PID: 21938
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void maps.ei.bz.o()' on a null object reference
at maps.ei.n.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i$a.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:115)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onResume(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onResume(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$7.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onResume(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onResume(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2020)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1107)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:926)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.startPendingDeferredFragments(FragmentManager.java:1276)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1634)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2108)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2771)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9520)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
```

Comment: Could you post your code? May be the problem is in layout inflation?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that onResume() is being called on your MapView before the GoogleMap has been initialized.

To avoid this problem make sure that when you create the SupportMapFragment you then call getMapAsync() on it and don't add the fragment to your pager view before the OnMapReadyCallback() is triggered.

e.g. when you create the MapFragment:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
               .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);

mapFragment.getMapAsync(onMapReadyCallback);
```

And then in the callback:

```
OnMapReadyCallback onMapReadyCallback = new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            addFragmentToPagerView();
        }
    };
```